# Arduino HC-05 with Android BluetoothChat Sample

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth

**Background**

I'm working on a project to connect an Android app with an Arduino board through bluetooth (Arduino Uno with an HC-05 module).  So I started development from the Arduino side, temporarily using the Bluetooth Terminal apps on the Play Store to simulate any data I have to transfer.  Now I'm moving onto the Android side of it.

Naturally, I went straight for the BluetoothChat sample (https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) to get a head start.  Googling online, it seems a one line change should get to BluetoothChat connected to my HC-05 module.

**Problem**

So I can't connect my BluetoothChat to the Arduino with HC-05.  The Arduino project should work, it connects fine to a variety of Bluetooth Terminal apps on the Play Store.

The only change I have made to the BluetoothChat sample is changing the code in BluetoothChatService.java:

From

```
    // Unique UUID for this application
private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
        UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
        UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");
```

To

```
// HC-05 UUID  "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
        UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
        UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

I was under the impression that was the only change I needed to make to allow my BluetoothChat sample to start moving.  Something like this (http://blog.onaclovtech.com/2012/04/modifying-bluetooth-chat.html), albeit it looks to be an older version of BluetoothChat.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you choose that particular UUID ? Just random of find any info in the HC-05 UUID service number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I found my own solution, it's necessary to change the name of the device as well to match the HC-05.  If I'm running a plain module out of the box (not in this case) you need to set:

```
// Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
private static final String NAME_SECURE = "BluetoothChatSecure";
private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BluetoothChatInsecure";
```

To:

```
private static final String NAME_SECURE = "HC-05";
private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "HC-05";
```